# How can i pass the basemodel class to the partial view, when i used this partial view into the view where i am using tuple of two clases in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view in which i m using tuple of two classes to render it like this.

```
@model Tuple<SAP.DTO.ViewData.IndentmstViewData, SAP.DTO.ViewData.IndentdetViewData>
```

and i am passing data from controller

```
            IndentmstViewData model1 = new IndentmstViewData();
            IndentdetViewData model2 = new IndentdetViewData();
            var model = new Tuple<IndentmstViewData, IndentdetViewData>(model1, model2);
            model.Item1.GetMenuData = GetMenuByUser();
            return View(model);
```

But in my layout page i used a partial page to render menu,partial page model used :

```
@model SAP.DTO.ViewData.BaseViewData
```

And when i run the application it throws an error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Tuple`2[SAP.DTO.ViewData.IndentmstViewData,SAP.DTO.ViewData.IndentdetViewData]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SAP.DTO.ViewData.BaseViewData'.

Comment: In your method you just return view Where you use partial view can share code

Comment: Just return partial view and render @Html.Partial("MenuView") or @{  
    Html.RenderPartial("_employee");  
}

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-string?rq=1